# Excel Userform Listbox Empty Row

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I'm making a User form with a listbox and a delete button. The list box grab data from a table and display it into the listbox row. When clicking on Delete, I added in a function to tell the user to select a row if no row from the listbox has been selected. I tried to added in a function to tell the user there's nothing to delete if they select a empty row. It [didn't work as intended and just continued on with the script.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOueI.png)

Here's what the start of the script looks like, let me know if I need to add in the rest of the script.

```
Private Sub Delete_Click()
    If Not ListBox1.Selected(ListBox1.ListIndex) Then
        MsgBox "Please select a row to delete"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    If Len(Trim(ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex))) = 0 Then '<-- this is the line that dont work
        MsgBox "Nothing to delete here"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim response As VbMsgBoxResult
    response = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete the selected rows?", vbYesNo, "You sure?")
    
    'If no then do nothing
    If response = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Dim selectedRows As New Collection
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Set ws = wb.Sheets("Table")

        'Store the indices of the selected rows in a collection
        For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
            If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
                selectedRows.Add i
            End If
        Next i
    
        'Delete the rows from the ListBox and the data source
        If selectedRows.Count > 0 Then
            'Sort the indices in descending order to avoid issues with deleting rows while iterating through the collection
            For i = selectedRows.Count To 1 Step -1
                ListBox1.RemoveItem selectedRows(i)
                Worksheets("Table").ListObjects("Table1").ListRows(selectedRows(i) + 1).Delete
            Next i
        End If
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = Worksheets("Table").Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row 'find last filled cell in column Q

        Dim n As Long
        For n = 4 To lastRow ' start with Q4
            If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Table").Range("Q" & n)) Then
                Worksheets("Table").Range("Q" & n).Value = n - 3 'subtract 3 to start at 1 instead of 4
            End If
        Next n

        ListBox1.Clear
        Call UserForm_Initialize
    End If
End Sub
```

I've also tried these but no luck

```
If ListBox1.ListIndex > -1 And Len(ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex)) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Nothing to delete here"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

```
If ListBox1.ListIndex > -1 And ListBox1.ListCount > 0 And Trim(ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex)) = "" Then
    MsgBox "Nothing to delete here"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

```
If Not ListBox1.Selected(ListBox1.ListIndex) Then
    MsgBox "Please select a row to delete"
     Exit Sub
ElseIf Len(ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex)) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Nothing to delete here"
     Exit Sub
End If
```

[Solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3zuS.png), Idk why it's treating a empty row as a special character. Using replace, we turn that special character into "". Idk how it works, but it does. If someone can shine a light on what is going on, please do so.

```
ElseIf Len(Replace(ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex), vbTab, "")) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Nothing to delete here"
     Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: `If ListBox1.ListIndex = -1 then msgbox "Select a row to delete"`

Comment: The line`If Not ListBox1.Selected(ListBox1.ListIndex) Then
        MsgBox "Please select a row to delete"` work as intended. If there's no row selected it gives me the msg "Please select a row to delete"

Comment: That is the whole point. you do not need so many `Ifs`. The code that I gave you will fire if user doesn't select anything in the listbox.

Comment: I actually do need all the if statement. Maybe I should paste the whole code in so you can see why. If I try to delete a empty row then it end up throwing a error. Will come back with the whole script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I started throwing spaghettis at the wall and it finally stuck. So I believe this replace tab characters with "". IDK why there are tab characters in there in the first place when my script to fill the table dont put any tab characters in.

```
ElseIf Len(Replace(ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex), vbTab, "")) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Nothing to delete here"
     Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: But this is the answer to my question. Do i just leave it unaswer and update my post?

Comment: I've already tried those while I was looking for the answer myself. The answer that i posted above is the answer. So using `Len(Replace(ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex), vbTab, ""))` is the way to solve it.

Comment: If your data can have `vbTab` then instead of `REPLACE` use `If Len(Trim(Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(ListBox1.ListIndex))) = 0 Then` to handle such characters. So if the cell has `vbCrLf` instead of `vbTab` then it will still work. Else you will have to write a separate `If` to handle that as well.

Comment: No that didn't work. I guess `Replace` is the way to go in my case. Using what you just gave me went right back to where i started.

Comment: I just tested `If Len(Trim(Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(vbTab))) = 0 Then` and it works... Anyway, I leave it to you